# Can't uninstall mySQL due to Connector/Net compnenet that cant be removed/updated

Tags: mysql, installation

I had an mySQL installed on my computer (WIN7) and then I wanted to unInstall it - so I uninstalled it using the add/remove componenet in my control panel (I looked for everything that has mysql in the title and then -> unInstall).
Later, I wanted to install mySQL again, so I downloaded the latest version and then open the setup file. 
For some strange reason the MySQL installer thinks I have the old "Connector/Net compnenet" installed already ("Welcome back!") and if I try to upgrade it (or uninstall it) the proccess is failing in the middle.
that prevents me from reInstalling mySQL again...
I also went to regedit and deleted the relevant mySQL entireis. that did not work...
I saw that this is a common problem in mySQL but does anyone have soultion for this? even a workaround will do..
Thanks!

from the log:

.

.

.

1: Removing shortcuts

1: Removing system registry values

1: UnregisterPerfCounterData

1: RollbackUnregisterPerfCounterData

1: Failed to install performance counters.  (-2147024894         )

1: Unpublishing Product Features

1: Unpublishing assembly information

1: Updating component registration

1: InstallInitialize

1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 6.9.5 2: {5E5D3141-7714-4B2E-8BF2-650C8EF65E3E} 3: 3

1: The action 'Upgrade' for product 'Connector/NET 6.9.5' failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem, try use nuget. it works for me...
[PM> Install-Package MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.5)